# Highcharts: Pie Chart not properly align upon loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts, pie-chart

so i have a pie chart that's inside an iframe and when the page loads the pie charts are not properly align

Here's an image of it:
[image]

But when i uncheck any of the labels it will align properly and even i check it again it stays align properly

[image]

the problem is only upon loading the page.
can anyone know why this happens?.
thanks

Comment: does your screen get resized on page load ?

Comment: i don't think so.  but if i uncheck any labels it aligns properly

Comment: Can you paste your full code or recreate the issue on jsfiddle/codepen/etc.?